# Segmentation fault when media played using libavcodec

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, codec

Myself trying to play media using libavcodec as backend.I downloaded ffmpeg-2.0.1 and installed using ./configure,make and make install.
While trying to run an application to play an audio file, i'm getting segmentation fault while checking for the first audio stream.my program is like

```
AVFormatContext* container = avformat_alloc_context();
if (avformat_open_input(&container, input_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    die(“Could not open file”);
}

if (av_find_stream_info(container) < 0) {
    die(“Could not find file info”);
}

av_dump_format(container, 0, input_filename, false);
int stream_id = -1;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < container->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (container->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        stream_id = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

> Segmentation fault occurs at if(container->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO)

How can i fix this? I am working in ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: When i did gdb to i am getting segmentation fault from 0xb6f74985 in av_strstart () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libavutil.so.51

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to allocate your `AVFormatContext` at the begginning.

Also the function `av_find_stream_info` is deprecated, you have to change it to [`avformat_find_stream_info`](http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__decoding.html#gad42172e27cddafb81096939783b157bb) :

```
av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();

AVFormatContext* container = NULL;
if (avformat_open_input(&container, input_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    die(“Could not open file”);
}

if (avformat_find_stream_info(container, NULL) < 0) {
    die(“Could not find file info”);
}

// av_dump_format(container, 0, input_filename, false);

int stream_id = -1;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < container->nb_streams; i++) {
    if (container->streams[i]->codec->codec_type==AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) {
        stream_id = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Also I'm not sure that `av_dump_format` was useful here...

---

**EDIT :**
Did you tried something like :

```
av_register_all();
avcodec_register_all();

AVFormatContext* container = NULL;
AVCodec *dec;

if ( avformat_open_input(&container, input_filename, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
    // ERROR
}

if ( avformat_find_stream_info(container, NULL) < 0) {
    // ERROR
}

/* select the audio stream */
if ( av_find_best_stream(container, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO, -1, -1, &dec, 0) < 0 ) {
    // ERROR
}
```

Comment: But still i am getting segmentation fault at the same place.I have not done allocating AVFormatContext.

Comment: @sarahjohn The segfault still occurs at the same line ?

Comment: @sarahjohn How many times the loop is executed before the segfault ?

Comment: loop doesn't getting executed.

Comment: @sarahjohn Can you test that `container->streams[i]->codec` is not `NULL` ?

Comment: Referring container->streams[i]->codec also causing the segfault.

Comment: @sarahjohn I suppose `container->streams[i]` causes a segfault too ?

Comment: yes, the same also causing segfault.by d way i have not allocated AVFormatContext

Comment: @sarahjohn I edited my post with something else. Can you try something like that ?

Comment: Did like that i am not getting any seg faults and the output when i gave an ogg file is like this                                       [theora @ 0x98fb7a0] 7 bits left in packet 82

Comment: @sarahjohn At the end, what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: i would like to play an audio file after decoding using libao.How i can find the decoder for the file and what was the reason for that segmentation fault.

Comment: I tried to open the codec using avcodec_open2(container->streams[ret]->codec, dec,NULL), then also segmentation fault continues.ret is the return value of container->streams[ret]->codec which is equal to zero.